# why the constraints reduce the accepted test cases

Tags: algorithm

this is a code i wrote to solve a problem on HackerRank "Recursive Digit Sum" 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/recursive-digit-sum
,the code suppose to take two digits as inputs (n,k) to calculate the super digit p. 
p is created when k is concatenated n times thats if, k=148 and n=3

p=148148148

sumdigit(P) = sumdigit(148148148)

= sumdigit(1+4+8+1+4+8+1+4+8)

= sumdigit(39)

= sumdigit(3+9)

= sumdigit(12)

= sumdigit(1+2)

= sumdigit(3)

= 3.

the Constraints

1<=n<10^(100000)

1<=k<=10^5

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
unsigned long int SumDigits(unsigned long int i) {
if (i < 10) {
return i;
}
else {
return i%10 + SumDigits(i/10);
}
}
int main() {
unsigned long int n,k,pos=0;
scanf("%ld %ld",&k,&n);
/**i would put the constraint however it reduces the accepted test cases*/
// if(k>=1&&k<pow(10,100000)&&n>=1&&n<pow(10,5)){
for(unsigned long int i=0;i<n;i++){
pos+=k;
k=k*( unsigned long int)pow(10,n);
  }
while(pos>=10){
pos=SumDigits(pos);
}
printf("%ld\n",pos);
 //}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You messed up coding the constraints. `k` has the limit of `n` and vice versa.

Comment: Also upper bound for `k` is inclusive.

Comment: Also, 10^100000 does not even come close to fitting into an unsigned long int.

Comment: if(k>=1&&k<=pow(10,5)&&n>=1&&n<pow(10,5))

Comment: Hint: input the number as a string.

Comment: Sergio Tulentsev is that what you meant ? or i got it wrong

Comment: @amr: no, that's not what I meant. Hint: take a _close_ look at the constraints and their values. And then your code.

Comment: @amr: also, those constraints are there just to give you an idea about size of input values. So here, for example, `n` can be a number with 100 000 digits. No native integer type in C can handle this. You'll have to come up with creative solutions.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev : ok now i understand , i'll try to find one :)